# Complicated when compiling in c++ but not in c (gcc)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

I have problem with multiply declaration in c++, but not in c.
You could see code for more information.

file main.c

```
#ifndef VAR
#define VAR
int var;
#endif
int main(){}
```

file other.c

```
#ifndef VAR
#define VAR
int var;
#endif
```

Compile with gcc

```
gcc main.c other.c
>> success
```

Compile with g++

```
g++ main.c other.c
Output:
/tmp/ccbd0ACf.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `var'
/tmp/cc8dweC0.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

My gcc and g++ version:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: That is weird, although you overly complicated it: http://ideone.com/zdZUg vs http://ideone.com/swhxi

Comment: What's in your CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS environment variables?

Comment: I've try extern "C" block, but it till doesn't work :(

Comment: I've changed `other.c` to `other.h` and `g++` compiled fine.

Comment: @VictorHugo that's cheating. `g++` will treat .h files as headers to be precompiled. Since main.c doesn't include it, there's only one definition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is formally incorrect in both C and C++ due to multiple definitions of variable `var`. It is just that this type of error was traditionally overlooked by C compilers as a popular non-standard extension. This extension is even mentioned in C language specification

> **J.5 Common extensions**
>
> The following extensions are widely used in many systems, but are not portable to all
>   implementations. [...]
>
> **J.5.11 Multiple external definitions**
>
> There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or
>   without the explicit use of the keyword extern; if the definitions disagree, or more than
>   one is initialized, the behavior is undefined (6.9.2).

But formally, you have absolutely the same multiple-definition error in both C and C++ languages. Ask your C compiler to behave more pedantically (disable extensions, if it has an option for that) and your C compiler shall also generate the very same error as your C++ compiler.

Again, you code contains multiple definitions of variable `var`, which is an error in both C and C++. Your `#ifdef` directives do not solve anything at all. Preperocessor directives cannot help you here. Preprocessor works locally and independently in each translation unit. It can't see across translation units.

If you want to create a *global* variable (i.e. the same variable shared by all translation units), you need to make *one and only one definition* of that variable

```
int var;
```

in one and only one translation unit. All other translation units should receive non-defining declarations of `var`

```
extern int var;
```

The latter is typically placed in a header file.

If you need an individual, independent variable `var` in each translation unit, simply define it in each translation unit as

```
static int var;
```

(although in C++ this usage of `static` is now deprecated and superseded by nameless namespaces).

Comment: +1. And if you really want to make sure it's defined make the definition (again in one translation unit only) 'int var = 0;'.  Then the compiler must treat it as a definition.

Answer (score 0):

The two `#define` directives have nothing to do with one another, as they are in different translation units (i.e., source files). The compiler processes the two source files in total isolation, so `defined(VAR)` is always false, and the contents of the `#ifndef` are always included.

If you mean to have one variable shared between multiple source files, there is a simple way to go about it: *define* it in one source file, and *declare* it in the other:

```
// other.cpp
int var;        // Definition.

// main.cpp
extern int var; // Declaration.
```

When linking, these will refer to the same `var`. Better yet, declare the variable in a header:

```
// other.h
extern int var;
```

Then files that need `var` can simply include the header:

```
// main.cpp
#include "other.h"
```

The difference you observe between C and C++ has to do with the treatment of globally declared identifiers in C versus C++. In C, any number of *tentative definitions* (having no storage class specifier and no initializer) may be merged together by the linker into a single symbol—so long as all actual definitions for that symbol ultimately have the same linkage and storage class. This is done using *weak* linker symbols.

C++, however, has no notion of a tentative definition, and treats an external declaration without storage class specifier as a definition. Thus G++ generates *strong* linker symbols, resulting in a conflict at link-time.

Comment: This doesn't explain the difference between C and C++

Comment: "The compiler processes": did you mean that c++ will expand all #ifndef (#ifdef) macro before linking?

Comment: @HaidangKoltec Yes. The precompiler and compiler run on each .cpp file creating obect (.o or .obj) files. Then the linker combines all .obj files into an executable.

Answer (score -1):

The visibility of global variables in compilation modules is subtly different between C and C++.

If these are intended to be different variables, enclose them in an anonymous namespace in each file.

```
namespace {
 int var;
}
```

If they are intended to be the SAME variable, one of them needs an `extern` decl-specifier, to avoid multiple definitions.

```
extern int var;
```

Your `#define VAR` isn't doing anything in the example you've posted. The definition is not carried across compilation modules.

Comment: This doesn't explain the difference between C and C++

Answer (score -1):

Inclusion guards are local to a translation unit. This means that when you do `#define VAR` in one `.cpp` file, it is not defined in any other files.